# Can somebody explain this to me? Qual Prep.

Tags: real-analysis

Prepping for the qual I was given a list of questions for RA, among them was this:

**Give a definition of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $\mathcal{I}$ be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all the open cubes in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Show $\mathcal{I}=\mathcal{B}$.**

So, the definition... straightforward...

**A "borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$" is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all open subests of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.**

But how am I suppose to prove the other part? He used the definition to form $\mathcal{I}$...

Comment: Is your worry that "open cube" and "open subset" mean the same thing? That would be a non-standard terminology, I believe.

Comment: The Borel $\sigma$-algebra a priori contains *all* the open sets. This $\mathcal{I}$ a priori contains just the open cubes, not all the other weird open sets.

Comment: Ah! I see y'alls point yea... Then... I guess... Now I just don't see a straight foward proof. My first thought is to use the complement of a sequence of cubes to form the other open sets. But that clearly excludes things like open spheres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathcal B$ is the smallest sigma algebra containing all the open sets in $\mathbb R^n$, and $\mathcal I$ is the smallest sigma algebra containing all the open cubes in $\mathbb R^n$.  Clearly $\mathcal B$ contains all the open cubes in $\mathbb R^n$.  Therefore, $\mathcal I \subseteq \mathcal B$.

To show that $\mathcal B \subseteq \mathcal I$, it suffices to show that $\mathcal I$ contains all the open *sets* in $\mathbb R^n$.  This will follow if you can show that every open set in $\mathbb R^n$ is a *countable* union of open cubes.

The case $n = 1$ (every open set in $\mathbb R$ is a countable union of open intervals) is well known.  In fact, more is true: there is a countable collection of open intervals in $\mathbb R$ of which every open set in $\mathbb R$ is the union.  In particular, $\mathbb R$ is second countable.

The general case follows from an inductive argument and the definition of the product topology.

Comment: I wasn't even thinking about countability! Shouldn't $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ being second-countable follow directly from the fact that it is the countable product of $\mathbb{R}$, a second-countable space?

Comment: ...nvm. That's what you were saying. I misunderstood at first to be suggesting that I needed to prove it inductively.

Comment: It's saying just a little more than second-countability, namely that there exists a countable basis consisting of open cubes.

Comment: Wouldn't the specificity that the "basis of open sets" be our cubes arise as a result of the condition that $\sigma$-algebras require $\bigcup_{k}E_{k}\in\Sigma$?

Comment: No.  Second countability has a priori nothing to do with sigma algebras.

Comment: What I was trying to say/ask was, since $\mathcal{I}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra including all open cubes in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and we know $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is second-countable, doesn't it directly follow that the basis of the imposed topology would be open cubes? --I don't see why more than those two facts need to be shown.

Comment: $\mathbb R^n$ second-countable means it has a countable basis.  It's another claim that there exists a countable basis for $\mathbb R^n$ consisting of cubes.

Comment: I see your point now.